# uniform convergence of $h_n$ on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $h_n : [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ given by 
$$
h_n(x) =\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x \ge 1/n \\ nx & \text{if }0 \le x< 1/n\end{cases}
$$
I need to find smaller domain for which $h_n \to h$ uniformly. At first thought, I thought $(0, \infty)$ however if I take $x_n = 1/2n$, I get $|h(x) - h_n(x)|=1/2$ but given any $\epsilon>0$, $h_n \to h$ uniformly on $(\epsilon, \infty)$. Can anyone confirm my answer?

Comment: Indeed, on $[a,\infty)$ for any $a>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on $(0,\infty)$, $h_n$ converges pointwise but not uniformly, but on any $(\epsilon,\infty)$ (or $[\epsilon,\infty)$, for that matter) for $\epsilon>0$ it converges uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it converges uniformy on $(\varepsilon,\infty)$. That's because, if you take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac1N<\varepsilon$, then$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(\forall x\in(\varepsilon,\infty)):n\geqslant N\implies h_n(x)=1.$$